Issue with CORS when trying to deploy via vercel
This problem has been solved..

Get rid of app.options('*', cors());. It shouldn't be needed, and is likely doing more harm than good. See if the error persists after that.

Removed and getting the same error

Inspect your browser's Console and figure out what response status the preflight request is getting.

Added an example to the post. This is just one example, I'm getting several of these errors

Try adding 'OPTIONS' explicitly to methods in your CORS middleware

Tried, Did not work

You added an example code snippet to your question, however preferably you should check your console logs and specifically the errors section to get more insight on what is causing the error. It would also be helpful if you check your Network tab also. Update your answer with these logs so we can debug it.

Solved it. Since I deployed the backend and frontend separately in vercel, the backend did not have an updated dependency list to build from.
After adding the dependencies to package.json in the server folder, everything works as it should.
